# How do I access parameters in parameterized CircleCI build

Tags: java, scala, build, continuous-integration, circleci

I want to start working with parametrized builds in CircleCI (https://circleci.com/docs/parameterized-builds).

The parameter I will pass is only an environment that I want to run my tests on.

Now, currently in my project I specify the environment in the config file:

```
web {
  environment = "https://someEnv-1pkt4jig1esam-234.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/"
}
```

And when I want to use it I invoke:

```
conf.getString("web.environment")
```

However, how do I use the parameter after retrieving it?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you pass in will be available in the environment variables. In Scala that seems to be accessed via `sys.env("YOUR_PARAMETER")` if you pass CircleCI 'YOUR_PARAMETER'.

I'd change your configuration file to use the current URL as a default and use the environment variable's value if present.